# Electron.js: change url of an iframe from the main process

Tags: iframe, electron

I need to redirect an iframe to a different url in my Electron application in the main process from the `onHeadersReceived` callback.

I've tried doing the redirect using `details.frame.executeJavaScript`:

```js
...
ses.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
  ...
  const pageUrl = new URL(pdfViewerURL.toString());
  pageUrl.searchParams.set('file', details.url);
  if (details.resourceType === 'subFrame') {
    details.frame?.executeJavaScript(`window.location.href="${pageUrl.toString()}"`, true);
    return;
  }
  callback({});
});
```

But it fails with this error in devtools:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///...
```

Comment: you seem to be loading a file in the iframe. Chrome doesn't allow you to do that

Comment: @pushkin yes, i need to load a small html/js web app into iframe (basically replace the default chrome pdf viewer with my custom one in iframe). any other alternative approaches i can try?

Comment: one thing that comes to mind is read the html file and then executeJavascript in the iframe to load all the html. Though if your page is loading scripts which are local files, I'm guessing there will be issues there